# How are Vue js entities/models mapped to DTO's in the controller?

Tags: .net, vue.js, asp.net-core, dto

If I was to run a post request on the front end using Vue.js and post the javascript entity model which has the data i need to post back, how is this mapped to a DTO in the controller where I post this entity back to? Is it done automatically based on the name of the properties or is there more to it than that?

```
this.$http.post(this.apiUrl, this.entity).then(saveCallback, this.dataReadFailure);
```

```
   public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] CreateUpdateDTO dto)
```

If i had something like the above how is the entity from the post request mapped to the DTO in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense. Vue.js has nothing to do with anything here. Data is posted one of two ways: a traditional form post (`form` element and various `input`s, `selects` and/or `textarea` elements contained within) or via AJAX. As AJAX, the content type of the post body is entirely up to you, so it could be `x-www-form-urlencoded` (same as traditional form post), `application/json` (a JSON object), `application/xml` (an XML document), or something else entirely.

Regardless of the means, a model binder is employed to somehow create C# objects from the posted data, based on the "bindings" (action param types and/or member types thereof). This is done by inspectively those bindings and then newing up one or more types and mapping the post data over, coercing types as necessary. That's a bit obtuse, I know. Simply, you're looking to create a 1-to-1 correspondence between what you've got as params for your action and what you're sending in the post. In other words, if you're binding to a class that has a member named `Foo`, there should be something named `Foo` in what you're sending.

If you're posting JSON, you're basically just going to build a pretty much exact copy of the C# class as a JavaScript object. If you're sending a tranditional form post (`x-www-form-urlencoded`), then you're going to need to follow model binding conventions to ensure that post values are projected properly. That means chaining with a `.` (i.e. `Foo.Bar` would map to a `Bar` member of the type of the `Foo` property), and Lists are handled via indexing (i.e. `ListPropery[N]` where `N` is the item index.